# Hypercube problem

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

$B$ is an n-dimensional hypercube, considered as undirected graph. Let $A$ be a subset of the vertices of $B$ such that $|A| \gt 2^{n-1}$.

Let $H$ is a subgraph of $B$ induced by $A$. Prove that $H$ has at least $n$ edges.

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does it seem like a Ramsey-theory-type problem?

Comment: can you explain a bit more :(...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory

Comment: Basically, the original problem in Ramsey theory says that if you have a large enough complete graph and color its edges by $n$ colors, you are destined to find a single-colored complete subgraph of a given size in the graph, for every such size. Namely, every edge-2-colored $K_6$ contains a single-colored $K_3$ (triangle).

Comment: I can't find a way how to solve the problem with this...

Comment: Nor can I, but it does seem similar. Namely, see the [Hales-Jewett theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hales-Jewett_theorem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Temporarily consider one of the $n$ coordinate axes.  Your hypercube has $2^{n-1}$ edges parallel to that axis.  Since $B$ has *more* than $2^{n-1}$ vertices, it must have two on the same one of those $2^{n-1}$ edges.  So $H$ has an edge parallel to the coordinate axis under consideration.  Apply this to all $n$ of the axes.

Comment: +1 Nice answer! Looks like you wrote $B$ instead of $A$ above.

Comment: thanks, I will try to solve it with it. If anyone has another ideas, please write them :)

Comment: there is simpler combinatoric solution Ill post tommorow (I can not post the solution now since this problem was homework for me and my fellow-students)

Answer (score 2):

We can build **n**-dimensional hypercube using two **$(n-1)$**-dimensional hypercubes.
This gives us the vertices set power **$|Vn| = 2^{n}$** for the n-dimensional hypercube **Gn(Vn, En)**.
Knowing **|Vn-1|** and **|En-1|** for **(n-1)**-dimensional hypercube we know **|En|** for **n**-dimensional hypercube. **|En| = 2*|En-1| + $2^{n-1}$**.

Solving this recurrence relation gives us **|En|** for any dimension. **|En| = $n*2^{n-1}$**.

Then we choose at least **$(2^{n-1}+1)$** vertices to be in the $A$ subset by choosing at most **$(2^{n-1} - 1)$** vertices that wont be in **$A$**.
We know that every vertex in **$n$**-dimensional hypercube is connected to **$n$** edges (or less if we remove some vertices).
So removing the maximum of **$(2^{n-1} - 1)$** vertices removes no more than **$r = (2^{n-1} - 1)*n$** edges.
**$r = (2^{n-1} - 1)*n = |En| - n$.**

It appers that the induced graph **H** has at least **|En| - r** edges.
**|En| - r = |En| - (|En| - n) = n.**
We can conclude that **H** has at least **n** edges.

Sorry if there is something unclear. English is not my native language. I would be glad if someone improves my post. I've done my best to format it and make it readable but I am new to LaTeX and I preferred not to use it for now.